# How to see values in Semantic-UI-React with multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

This is a really straight forward question.  Notice I have the multiple attribute.  When I select a value it just pushes a value into an array.  Hence, if I have multiple values it will give me an array with multiple values but not the specific option I'm choosing.

Now my question is how do I get that specific value when I **remove** it from the Dropdown?  I've searched google for an hour and haven't found an answer.

```
<Dropdown 
    options={options} 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
    search fluid multiple selection/>

onChange(e,  { value } ) {
        e.preventDefault();     
       // e.target.value DOESN'T WORK???!!!

    }
```

Comment: Try a simple approach? something like `onChange={e => console.log(e)}` would give you the full event object

Comment: Tried that doesn't work...  To elaborate, you can get whats being added but when you remove an option it doesn't provide any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Dropdown from Semantic UI doesn't seem to provide this functionality out of the box. However, there's a decent way of achieving this. First, create a state like:

```
this.state = {
  selected: [],
}
```

Then, bind a function to the Dropdown component like so:

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder="Skills"
  fluid
  multiple
  selection
  options={options}
  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Once that's done, write the `handleChange` function to compare array lengths on every change. If state array is longer than whatever array you get from the dropdown, the item has been removed and you can check which one. Otherwise, dump the array into the state.

```
handleChange = (e, { value }) => {
    if (this.state.selected.length > value.length) { // an item has been removed
        const difference = this.state.selected.filter(
            x => !value.includes(x),
        );
        console.log(difference); // this is the item
        return false;
    }
    return this.setState({ selected: value });
};
```

You'll need a polyfill to run in IE8 and below though.

Comment: This doesn't return the specific value of what gets removed in the value array.

Comment: That's up to you though. If you store the value in the state and on every change compare the two, you can know if something is removed. Let me modify my answer

Comment: I know that however that's basically saying you're comparing two arrays which might not be considered a good solution.

Comment: I'm suggesting you make a controlled component yeah. Dropdown will feed you arrays, not changes in them, so there's not much you can do here. Imho the least harmful solution is to check lengths first, and then dive into looking for the difference

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works.  Could you maybe elaborate on the polyfill?  Will I need to install a npm package for this polyfill?

Comment: Anytime, oh yeah, if you wanted to support IE8 and below, you'd have to check for browser first, and if you detect it, MDN has a nice polyfill code for filter! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: There's one more thing as well, which could work in theory and eliminate the need for array filtering. Dropdown exposes `onLabelClick` event, which fires whenever a user clicks the label, but NOT the X that's clicked when you're removing something. If you wanted to, you could hide the X, listen to label clicks, and then ‘onLabelClick={e => handleChange(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)}` would give you the clicked value, which you remove from state, and feed that state back to dropdown as `value`. I will see if there's a nice solution for this that lets you keep the X as well.